# How do I view or download the call transcript in Azure Communication Services?

Tags: azure, azure-communication-services

The documentation for Azure Communication Services call transcription shows that obviously the call transcript is available somewhere: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/how-tos/calling-sdk/call-transcription?pivots=platform-android. BUT, I can't find the method for downloading the transcript anywhere. Please someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: By any chance, did you find any way to get video call transcripts using either Azure communication services SDK or any Azure communication service API?

Did you raise any feedback request in the portal mentioned in the portal? I didn't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Azure Communication Services do not offer API access to download transcriptions. Please submit your idea to [the feedback portal](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/81ff6d2b-0c25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858) to increase its visibility and to let others vote for it.